# How can I profile a MonoMac application?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, profiling, monomac

I'm trying to grab some profiling information from my MonoMac application, but can't get it to work, I have tried this:

```
MONO_ENV_OPTIONS="--trace --gc=sgen --profile=log:heapshot" App.app/Contents/MacOS/AppSync
```

But this isn't working.

Any idea of how I can get this to run?

Comment: What do you mean with not working, is it not printing any profiling data or are you getting some crash at runtime ?

Comment: Doesn't print anything and I believe the `--trace` option should make it trace all method calls.

Comment: Which version of Mono and MonoDevelop are you using ?  Have you tried using one of the [MonoMac Samples](https://github.com/mono/monomac/tree/master/samples).  I just tried the macdoc sample with MonoDevelop 3.0.4 and Mono 2.10.9 and it's working fine for me.

Comment: That's weird, I'm using MonoDevelop 3.0.3 and Mono 2.10.9. Will try with the samples and see how it goes.